# refresh kitchen sink sencha's left hand side menu

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i want to refresh kitchen sink(http://pydictionary.appspot.com/) sencha's left hand side menu whose data source is json. I have changed the data in .json file but menu doesn't load new data in menu. 
data is coming from leftmenu.json

```
Ext.regModel('Demo', {
fields: [
    {name: 'text',        type: 'string'},
    {name: 'source',      type: 'string'},
    {name: 'leaf',      type: 'boolean'}
      ]});

sink.StructureStore = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
model: 'Demo',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'leftmenu.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'tree',
        root: 'items'
    }
}});
```

i am trying to reload it in following ways...but not working

```
            sink.StructureStore.setProxy(sink.StructureStore.getProxy()); 
            sink.StructureStore.getRootNode().removeAll(); 
            sink.StructureStore.load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just need to add one magical line which i missed

```
    Ext.getCmp("nestedList").onBackTap();
```

this menu is loaded when user clicks  "Table of contents option" of first level menu. now its working

Answer (score 0):

if your code is correct, after load() list data should automatically change.  And we dont need to change the url everytime. only load will work